# VBA PowerPoint run-time Error 438: Method or Data Member Not Found for ChartTitle.TextFrame

Tags: vba, macos, powerpoint

I'm encountering a run-time error 438 while working with VBA in PowerPoint. The specific error message is "Method or Data Member Not Found" and it's occurring at the line `Set chartTitleTextFrame = cChart.ChartTitle.TextFrame` within my code. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
' Check if the chart has a title

    If cChart.HasTitle Then
        Set chartTitleTextFrame = cChart.ChartTitle.TextFrame
        ' Set chart title text and font properties
        With chartTitleTextFrame.TextRange.Font
            .Name = "Montserrat"
            .Bold = True
            .Size = 26
            .Color.RGB = RGB(107, 27, 85)
        End With
```

I've double-checked the object hierarchy and it seems that `cChart.ChartTitle` does have the `TextFrame` property according to the documentation. However, when I run the code, it throws a 438 error. If I remove `.TextFrame`, then I get a 13 error. I'm not sure why I'm unable to access the `TextFrame` property in this specific context.

Could anyone provide insight into what could be causing this error and how I might resolve it? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Additional Information:

- I'm using PowerPoint with the most recent version on my mac.
- I've tried assigning the TextFrame to a variable (`Dim chartTitleTextFrame As TextFrame`) and setting it to `cChart.ChartTitle.TextFrame`.
- I've also tried using `.TextFrame2` instead of `.TextFrame`, but encountered the same issue.

Please let me know if there's any additional information needed. Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Not sure where you're seeing `TextFrame` in the [object browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYbg7.png) or the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.chart.charttitle)

Answer (score 1):

Provided code to loop through all charts on the first slide. Updated it as needed.

Using `.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font` to change font properties, and changing font color with `.Fill.ForeColor.RGB`.

```vb
Sub SetChartTitleFont()
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim oChart As Chart
    Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
        If oShape.HasChart Then
            Set oChart = oShape.Chart
            With oChart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
                .Name = "Montserrat"
                .Bold = True
                .Size = 26
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(107, 27, 85)
            End With
        End If
    Next oShape
End Sub
```